# Use different sound card for microphone vs audio output

Tags: audio, input-device, audio-playback

I recently bought a [USB sound card](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001MSS6CS) to improve the audio output on my pi while continuing to use my [USB microphone](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B008CNZOJY) for audio input.

The problem is that I do not know how to configure the pi to use the USB sound card as the default for audio out while continuing to use the separate USB mic for audio in.   The USB sound card technically has a 3.5 mm mic in but I would rather not buy another microphone (non-USB) just to get this working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I set up my `~/.asoundrc` like below and it allowed playback from the USB sound card and input from the separate USB mic.

```
pcm.!default {
     type hw
     card 0 #card 0 is USB sound card
}

ctl.!default {
     type hw
     card 2 #card 2 is USB microphone
}
```

Comment: For future reference, the "formatting tips" sidebar on the Ask Questions page has a [link to a more in depth reference](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) and those little symbols in the editor topbar *do* all serve some purpose.  You are not limited to using raw html and `&nbsp;` for spacing ;)

Comment: How did you configure `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` for that? Setting up `~/.asoundrc` like that does not work for me.